# Spring WS 2.1.0: Endpoint interceptors order

Tags: java, spring, interceptor, spring-ws, endpoint

I have a web service on Spring WS with two endpoint interceptors. XML configuration looks like this

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.someorg.security.SignatureInterceptor"/>
    <bean class="org.someorg.common.LoggingInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg value="logger_1"/>
    </bean>    
</sws:interceptors>
```

SignatureInterceptor verifies signature of incomming SOAP Envelope and signs outgoing SOAP Envelope.

LoggingInterceptor stores raw SOAP data (byte array) in a database.

I need SignatureInterceptor to invoke before LoggingInterceptor and writing interceptor beans this way I expected it would solve my problem. But according to log messages LoggingInterceptor invokes first, so unsigned data stores in a database.

Then I changed configuration simply swaped bean declarations and they began to work as I expected

```
<sws:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.someorg.common.LoggingInterceptor">
        <constructor-arg value="logger_1"/>
    </bean>    
    <bean class="org.someorg.security.SignatureInterceptor"/>    
</sws:interceptors>
```

But this case is not clear to me. How can I explicitly set the invoke order of interceptors?

Comment: See http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?59921-Order-of-Interceptors for example of selective request/response logging in correct order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order should be the way you have specified it (except if they are mapped to a specific endpoint url, in which case they are handled last) - do note that the order in which the order in which the handleResponse is handled is opposite of handlRequest -

Ideally in your case you should see:

1. SignatureInterceptor.handleRequest(..)
2. LoggingInterceptor.handleRequest(..)
3. Endpoint handles request
4. LoggingInterceptor.handleResponse()
5. SignatureInterceptor.handleResponse()

I tried a small test and it works the same way for me.

Comment: Thanks for helpful explanation. I really didn't notice that the order of handleResponse is opposite to handleRequest. Now I've understood how interceptor chain works